# Having problems with writing a method to find the index of the biggest integer in my ArrayList

Tags: java

I am having problems in creating a method that will find the index of the biggest integer.

I have tried creating plenty of methods but I was only recently introduced to finding the index of a value in a list, and I still am unable to find the best, let alone a working way. By index I assumed that it is the position of the value within the list given (please correct me if I am wrong).

My Current Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindBiggest2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Enter any amount integers (0 to stop): ");

    int integer = input.nextInt();
    while(integer != 0) {
        integerList.add(integer);
        integer = input.nextInt();
    }
    input.close();
    if(integerList.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("list is empty");
        return;
    }
     System.out.println("\nThe integers entered are: ");
    // displaying ids
    for(int i=0; i<integerList.size(); i++)
        System.out.print(integerList.get(i)+" ");
        System.out.println();

    // finding biggest id
    int bInt = integerList.get(0); // initializing bid id with first element
    for(int i=1; i<integerList.size(); i++)
        if(bInt < integerList.get(i))
        bInt = integerList.get(i);

    System.out.println("The biggest integer in the array is: "+ bInt);
    }

}
```

My current output (Example):

```
Enter any amount of integers (0 to stop):
1
2
3
4
5
6
0

The integers entered are:
1 2 3 4 5 6 
The biggest integer in the array is: 6
```

These are my requirements of my output:

The output of the program should firstly display all integers, and then
indicate the biggest integer among them as well as the index of the biggest integer in the 1D
array.

Comment: `bInt = i;` in the loop then print `integerList.get(bInt)` for the integer and print `bInt` for the index. Your `if` condition will be changed to `if(integerList.get(bInt)...`

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, integerList.size()).boxed().max(Comparator.comparing(integerList::get))`

Comment: Am I able to see the coding of finding the index implemented with my coding? I am so sorry as I am still new to this.

Answer (score 1):

So your index in this loop:

```
int bInt = integerList.get(0); // initializing bid id with first element
for(int i=1; i<integerList.size(); i++) // i = index
    if(bInt < integerList.get(i))
    bInt = integerList.get(i);
```

would be i. Along with int bInt, you'll want an int maxIntegerIndex to hold that value until the for loop concludes.

One stylistic choice I'd suggest that you can feel free to ignore is using curly braces to explicitly declare what code is running in a loop / if statement. This will prevent issues later on in code reading and execution where it appears code should run but isn't. It'll save you a lot of time tracking down seemingly broken code down the road and costs almost nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having problems in creating a method that will find the index of
>   the biggest integer.

In the same way that you are storing the largest value, also store the value of "i" in a separate variable:

```
// finding biggest id AND the index where it was found
int index = 0;
int bInt = integerList.get(0); // initializing bid id with first element
for(int i=1; i<integerList.size(); i++) {
    if(bInt < integerList.get(i)) {
        bInt = integerList.get(i);
        index = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("The biggest integer in the array is: "+ bInt);
System.out.println("It was found at Index: "+ index);
```